# How can I know how much jobs were done in OpenMP "for directive"?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'd like to know the progress of a for-loop using OpenMP.
I know reduction directive doesn't work, but I wrote like this:

```
#pragma omp for reduction (+:sum)
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++){
    // do something that takes about 10seconds 
    sum++;
#pragma omp critical
    cout << sum << " / " << size << endl; 
    }
```

this will return something like this:

```
1 / 100
1 / 100
2 / 100
1 / 100
...
```

but I want this:

```
1 / 100
2 / 100
3 / 100
```

.    ..

Is there any way to get the correct `sum` value during `reduction` directive?
or should I use another method?

Comment: This is tricky because you need to do a reduction sum in the middle of the OpenMP region. Each thread has its own copy of the `sum` variable - which are only added together at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reduction` clause has a very well defined meaning, explained in detail in section 2.9.3.6 of the [latest OpenMP standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf). I doubt you will be able to use it for the purpose you described above.

Anyhow, it may be possible to implement that behavior with only slight modifications to your source:

```
sum = 0
#pragma omp for shared(sum) schedule(guided)
for (int i=0; i < size; i++){
    // do something that takes about 10seconds 
#pragma omp critical(PRINT)
    {
      sum++;
      cout << sum << " / " << size << endl;     
    }
}
```

In this way you are ensured that only one thread at a time is trying to increment 'sum' and print it on screen. Given the long time each iteration takes, this synchronization should not give rise to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another method. Reduction creates a thread-private variable (in your case `sum`) which it reduces only at the end, when all threads join. Reduction is highly implementation-dependent. It could wait for all threads to finish, it could reduce as threads finish, it could create a reduction tree, etc.

Instead, to track progress, you could have another variable `numDone`, which each thread atomically increases.

**EDIT**

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Reduction) explains it pretty well:

> reduction(operator | intrinsic : list): the variable has a local copy
>   in each thread, but the values of the local copies will be summarized
>   (reduced) into a global shared variable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the need for communications (from updating a shared counter), you could just print out the thread number together with the number of items it has processed so far, i.e.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   int count = 0;
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)           // or whatever schedule you want
  for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
    // ...
    printf("@ %d: done %d loops\n",
           omp_get_thread_num(),++count);   // should not need a critical section
  }
}
```

In your particular case, since the work takes about 10sec, any communications are not critical, but it may be worthwhile to use a dynamic schedule, in particular if the work can vary between different `i`.